# Rankings keep dropping from #4 - #36 then back up again?

Tags: google-search, google-ranking

For the last few weeks every 3 - 4 days my clients site goes from #4 on google right down to #36. Then after a few days it shoots back up to number #3 but today its back down to #36.

There isn't anything untoward on Google Webmaster Tools, no Duplicate content or anything like that. The Page Auth is 26 whilst not great our top competitor is only 33.

Do you have any ideas what could be causing this?

Search terms is '*plus size lingerie*'

[image]

Comment: This is normal. Rankings aren't static and are constantly in flux.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how I can stabilise things a little, I could understand a slight change in rankings maybe 5 - 6 places but from #4 to #36 overnight seems radical.

Comment: It is the times. Google has made several updates including Panda 4.2 which is rolling out slowly over months. Since at least May, but especially Aug., Sept., and Oct., it seems that people are complaining about larger fluctuations. Part of what I am seeing are searches that I have not seen on my site before pulling lower performing pages upward and more typical searches occurring less. This is a part of the reordering of the SERPs.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for that, it would explain it... I wish I knew how to get it back up though we're running at about 40% less sales at the moment as this is our main keyword